# Batch number missing in version number in civicrm.php

Tags: wordpress, 4.7

By default, WordPress uses the version information provided in ../civicrm/civicrm.php. However, the batch number is missing here:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: CiviCRM
Description: CiviCRM - Growing and Sustaining Relationships
Version: 4.7
Author: CiviCRM LLC
Author URI: http://civicrm.org/
Plugin URI: http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/WordPress+Installation+Guide+for+CiviCRM+4.7
License: AGPL3
Text Domain: civicrm
Domain Path: /languages
*/
```

WordPress uses the following code to extract the version information from a plugin:

```
$data = get_plugin_data("~/civicrm/civicrm.php");
$version = $data['Version'];
```

I am using this functionality to automate keeping track of my fixes until CiviCRM and other plugins make the necessary corrections in the next release.

> Would it be possible to update civicrm.php to add the batch number?
>   So, it will return 4.7.12 instead of 4.7.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the more granular CiviCRM version data with:

```
$version_file = CIVICRM_PLUGIN_DIR . 'civicrm/civicrm-version.php';
if ( file_exists( $version_file ) ) {
    require_once $version_file;
    $civicrm_version = civicrmVersion();
}
```

Comment: This does not fix the fact that WordPress is looking for the version information in the header when it displays it on the plugin page.

Comment: True, but what problem does that solve that the code above does not?

Comment: Having the WordPress plugin page display the entire version number is the problem I would like solved. Then I can give CiviCRM code that can be adapted to allow WordPress to update CiviCRM via the plugin page. No more coping and extracting of zip files. Wouldn't that be an improvement.

Comment: It would. I'd be very interested to hear your strategy for doing this.

Comment: My strategy is based on the following article: [article link](https://helpstring.wordpress.com/2012/04/18/a-guide-to-the-wordpress-http-api-automatic-plugin-updates/). It consists of one class that needs to be added to the plugin and a web page to respond to the WordPress requests. The code involves implementing 2 filters **pre_set_site_transient_update_plugins** and **plugins_api**. I'd be happy to answer any questions you have.

Comment: Are you planning to host these auto-updates and provide the associated API responses? I'd imagine people might be reluctant to trust an unknown third-party for this kind of thing.

Comment: No. I have enough on my plate with 4 of my own software projects to host. I was kind of hoping that CiviCRM.org might be interested.I have a further restriction on my client's site that I don't have SSH access. Imagine doing backups and moving zip files via your ISP's user interface.

Comment: Back to the original post. The version data is in the header of the main plugin file, so that even if the plugin is deactivated, one can still see the information.

Comment: @Codedogs I actually agree with what you want - the version number of the plugin *should* match Civi's version number. Quite how to make that happen is beyond me however - you will need to get the committers to make sure that it is updated prior to every minor version bump. Perhaps open an issue on Jira to get their attention?

Comment: Do you have a URL for Jira?

Comment: https://issues.civicrm.org